# Unable to download Spring web mvc dependencies using Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

Im using MAVEN to download Spring dependencies but have a unique issue

when I try to download 4.1.3.RELEASE it does not download the dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

but this one works.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here is my complete POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>FirstWebproject</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>FirstWebproject Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.17</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>FirstWebproject</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks to me like the jar is corrupt. Remove it from your local repo and give it another try (force download of snapshot and releases).

Comment: I remove it from .m2/repository but that does not work..Is there any other place I need to remove it.

Comment: If you are using `4.2.0` core, why not use `<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
 <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>` ?

Comment: how you can say its not downloaded?

Comment: When I expand the jar, I dont see the packages being listed

Comment: Try `mvn clean install -U` for force updates and see if it works

Comment: In some cases, the .m2/settings.xml may be setting another maven repository.